# How to extract the sequence from FASTA file using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, file-handling

I have a `FASTA` file with many Protein sequences. I need to read the FASTA file, delete the header and save the sequences in different variables. Any suggestions on how to do it in Perl (please not Bio Perl)?

Example for the FASTA file:

```
gi|542264878|ref|XP_003460692.2| PREDICTED: myosin heavy chain, fast skeletal muscle-like, partial [Oreochromis niloticus|
KCFEKPKPAKGKAEAHFSLVHYAGTVDYNITGWLDKNKDPLNDSVVQLYQKSSNKLLALLYVAHAGGEEAGGGKKGGKKKGGSFQTVSALFRENLGKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCLIPNETKTPGLMENFLVIHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYGDFKQRYKVLNASVIPEGQFIDNKKAS
```

And I want only the sequence:

```
KCFEKPKPAKGKAEAHFSLVHYAGTVDYNITGWLDKNKDPLNDSVVQLYQKSSNKLLALLYVAHAGGEEAGGGKKGGKKKGGSFQTVSALFRENLGKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCLIPNETKTPGLMENFLVIHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYGDFKQRYKVLNASVIPEGQFIDNKKAS
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like a fair question.

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is OK for you, then this simple one-liner does it

```
# cat test 
gi|542264878|ref|XP_003460692.2| PREDICTED: myosin heavy chain, fast skeletal muscle-like, partial [Oreochromis niloticus| KCFEKPKPAKGKAEAHFSLVHYAGTVDYNITGWLDKNKDPLNDSVVQLYQKSSNKLLALLYVAHAGGEEAGGGKKGGKKKGGSFQTVSALFRENLGKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCLIPNETKTPGLMENFLVIHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYGDFKQRYKVLNASVIPEGQFIDNKKAS

# awk '{print $NF}' test
KCFEKPKPAKGKAEAHFSLVHYAGTVDYNITGWLDKNKDPLNDSVVQLYQKSSNKLLALLYVAHAGGEEAGGGKKGGKKKGGSFQTVSALFRENLGKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCLIPNETKTPGLMENFLVIHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYGDFKQRYKVLNASVIPEGQFIDNKKAS
```

Here is `perl` way:

```
# perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' test 
KCFEKPKPAKGKAEAHFSLVHYAGTVDYNITGWLDKNKDPLNDSVVQLYQKSSNKLLALLYVAHAGGEEAGGGKKGGKKKGGSFQTVSALFRENLGKLMTNLRSTHPHFVRCLIPNETKTPGLMENFLVIHQLRCNGVLEGIRICRKGFPSRILYGDFKQRYKVLNASVIPEGQFIDNKKAS
```

Refer this link for Per one-liner explanation: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of

Comment: @slayedbyucifer Your answer is not fit for other fasta files.?

Comment: @Hussain, This answer is specific to the sample data given. That's all.